# Suggest a alternate query

Tags: mysql, performance

```
select  rcptto
    from  EmailDeliveryTracking edt
    where  edt.event in (2,3,4)
      and  edt.errordetail <> 9501
      and  not exists 
      ( SELECT  1
            from  EmailDeliveryTracking edt2
            where  edt.rcptto = edt2.rcptto
              and  edt2.event = 1
              and  edt2.eventtime >= date_add(now(),INTERVAL -6 month) 
      )
    group by  rcptto
    having  count(*) >= 3 ;
```

EmailDeliveryTracking has 12101142 records.

Comment: Just one question.. Why?

Comment: can you execute show index in EmailDeliveryTracking and update the question

Comment: @sagi - its taking too much time

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka - all the columns of the EmailDeliveryTracking table has an index

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE EmailDeliveryTracking`

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
select rcptto
from EmailDeliveryTracking edt
where edt.event in (2, 3, 4) and
      edt.errordetail <> 9501 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from EmailDeliveryTracking edt2 
                  where edt.rcptto = edt2.rcptto and
                        edt2.event = 1 and
                        edt2.eventtime >= date_add(now(),INTERVAL -6 month
                 )
group by rcptto
having count(*) >= 3 ;
```

First, you should try indexes.  This is a bit tricky, the place to start is `EmailDeliveryTracking(rcptto, event, eventtime)` and perhaps `EmailDeliveryTracking(event, error_detail, rcptto)`.

Comment: Won't the `LEFT` mess up the `HAVING COUNT`?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to NOT EXISTS is a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Performance wise which one is best will vary on the number of records, indexes, etc.

```
SELECT  edt.rcptto
FROM  EmailDeliveryTracking edt
LEFT OUTER JOIN  EmailDeliveryTracking edt2  ON edt.rcptto = edt2.rcptto
AND    edt2.event = 1
AND    edt2.eventtime >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -6 MONTH)
WHERE  edt.event IN (2,3,4)
AND    edt.errordetail <> 9501
AND    edt2.rcptto IS NULL
GROUP BY  edt.rcptto
HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 3 ;
```

Does *EmailDeliveryTracking* have an index on *rcptto* ?

Comment: @Prabakaran - what other indexes do you have?

Comment: in all the columns of the EmailDeliveryTracking Table.

Comment: @Prabakaran - but do you have any indexes that cover multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `INDEX(event, rcptto, eventtime)`, in that order.

How many rows have `event in (2,3,4)`?  How many have `errordetail <> 9501`?  If the answers to these are relatively high (or low), there might be some other techniques to use to take advantage of it.